# Can I use Bitmap in a Brush, in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to use a picture instead of color in this code:

`brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);`

Ex: `brush = new SolidBrush(PICTURE);`

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use one of the Fill methods in Graphics class and a `TextureBrush`?

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("bitmap file path");
TextureBrush textureBrush = new TextureBrush(image);
graphics.FillEllipse(myTextureBrush, 0, 0, 200, 200);
```

Comment: my code is like this:

public Food(Random randFood)
       {
           x = randFood.Next(0, 29) * 10;
           y = randFood.Next(0, 29) * 10;

           brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

           width = 14;
           height = 14;

           foodRec = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
       }

should I put that you have given me somewhere here? (I'm new with c#)

Comment: I get an error and is says: 'The name "myTextureBrush' does not exict in the current....

Comment: You would have to use `TextureBrush` instead of a `SolidBrush`

Comment: I still get the same error:
private int x, y, width, height;
       private TextureBrush brush;
       public Rectangle foodRec;

       public Food(Random randFood)
       {
           x = randFood.Next(0, 29) * 10;
           y = randFood.Next(0, 29) * 10;

      
           width = 14;
           height = 14;

           Image image = Image.FromFile("c:\\apple.jpg"); 
           TextureBrush textureBrush = new TextureBrush(image); 
           Graphics.FillEllipse(myTextureBrush, 0, 0, 200, 200);
           foodRec = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
       }

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `TextureBrush` to do so

```
private void Button2_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(@"C:\Documents and Settings\" +
            @"All Users\Documents\My Music\music.bmp", true);

        TextureBrush texture = new TextureBrush(image1);
        texture.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile;
        Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillEllipse(texture, 
            new RectangleF(90.0F, 110.0F, 100, 100));
        formGraphics.Dispose();

    }
    catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error opening the bitmap." +
            "Please check the path.");
    }

}
```

Code snippet taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.texturebrush.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx).

[image]